# Baseball Spray Charts - R

Tags: r, visualization

I am looking to create a baseball field function that creates spray charts using section percentage vectors. Instead of using (x,y) coordinates, I am looking to create a spray chart that applies these percentage vectors to its corresponding location--also adjusting the background color based on size of value, maybe 20% results in dark green and 10% results in lighter green and < 5% results in white.

An example of data is shown below:

| RF | CF | LF | 3B | SS | 2B | 1B | C | P | LFTCENTER | UPTHEMIDDLE | RGHTCENTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 6 | 9 | 9 | 6 | 19 | 3 | 3 | 9 | 9 | 3 | 12 |

I would like to take this data and create an object that looks something like what's show below:

[image]

I would like to do this because my data isn't in-depth enough to have coordinates of batted ball position, so my spray chart would vary from the "normal" spray chart:

[image]

I have searched the web to create this spray chart I am looking for, but everything I found was formatted in different coding languages I am not familiar with. I was able to create these percentages quite easily from play-by-play data--which is helpful in itself, but I would like to create visualizations.

**Note**: I am working in R.

Comment: Where exactly are "LFTCENTER," "UPTHEMIDDLE," and "RGHTCENTER"? e.g., what areas are "UPTHEMIDDLE" rather than "C," "P," or "2B"? It might help if you sketched a mock-up and added to your question.

Comment: It sounds like you need to make a graphic template that defines the areas. For instance, what describes the "CF" zone? We might establish that, within the range of the graphic, its angular range is the middle third, and its distance from home is from 60 to 100% of the way to the back of the park. If you can describe those, then you could feed that into a custom function to plot each shape, e.g. using the `ggforce::geom_arc_bar` geom, which uses for input a radius range and an angular range.