# Creating Custom in R GGPlot to Fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I want to make these shapes in R, with each being its own shape (outlined in black). I then want to conditionally fill these with a value that I have. You can ignore the text... So it is seven shapes I want to graph together if that is possible. Thank you

Comment: Hello, please provide information of things you have already tried and what's not working.  Stack Overflow is not a "write my code for me" site.

Comment: Existing (unanswered) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75035346/baseball-spray-charts-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is relatively easy:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group = group, fill = value)) +
  geom_polygon(color = 'black', linewidth = 1.2) +
  geom_label(data = . %>% group_by(group) %>%
               summarize(x = ifelse(n() > 20, mean(x), mean(range(x))), 
                         y = ifelse(n() > 20, mean(y), sqrt(8)/2),
                         value = mean(value)), fill = 'white',
             aes(label = value), fontface = 4, size = 6) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("#e86a68", "#e86a68", 
                                   "#f0ea94", "#629353","#629353"),
                       values = c(0, 0.1, 0.55, 0.95, 1), guide = 'none') +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

It's creating a data frame of the polygons that is difficult:

```r
a  <- sqrt(8)/2 
b  <- a/2
s  <- sin(pi/8)
f1 <- function(a, b) 1.3 * seq(a, b, length.out = 20)
f2 <- function(a, b) sqrt(1.3^2 - f1(a, b)^2)
f3 <- function(a, b) seq(a, b, length.out = 20)
f4 <- function(a, b) sqrt(1 - f3(a, b)^2)

df <- data.frame(value = rep(c(-0.5, -0.2, 0.3, -0.2, -1.1, 0.5, 0.6), 
                             times = c(4, 22, 4, 22, 22, 22, 22)),
                 group = rep(letters[1:7], times = c(4, 22, 4, 22, 22, 22, 22)),
                 x = c(0, a, b, 0, 0, f3(b, -b), 0, 0, -b, -a, 0, 0, 
                       f1(b, s), 0, 0, f1(s, 0), 0, 0, f1(0, -s), 0, 0, 
                       f1(-s, -b), 0),
                 y = c(0, a, 1.5 * a, 0, 0, f4(b, -b) + a, 0, 0, 1.5 * a, 
                       a, 0, 0, f2(b, s), 0, 0, f2(s, 0), 0, 0, f2(0, -s), 0, 0, 
                       f2(-s, -b), 0))
```

---

**Edit**

MrFlick pointed out that this is a representation of a baseball field, in which case the above shape isn't quite right. You might want to instead use the following polygons:

```r
A <- sqrt(8)/2
B <- A/2
C <- 0.3 * sqrt(8)
D <- C * sin(pi/4)
f1 <- function(a, b) c(0, seq(a, b, length.out = 100), 0)
f2 <- function(a, b) c(0, sqrt(2.0001 - seq(a, b, len = 100)^2) + A, 0)
f3 <- function(a, b) c(0, sqrt(C^2 - seq(a, b, length.out = 100)^2) + C, 0)
df <- data.frame(value = rep(c(-.5, -.2, .3, -.2, -1.1, .5, .6), each = 102), 
                 group = rep(letters[1:7], each = 102),
                 x     = c(f1(A, B), f1(B, -B), f1(-B, -A), 
                           f1(C, D), f1(D, 0), f1(0, -D), f1(-D, -C)),
                 y     = c(f2(A, B), f2(B, -B), f2(-B, -A),
                           f3(C, D), f3(D, 0), f3(0, -D), f3(-D, -C)))
```

Which creates this picture with the same plotting code:

[image]

Comment: Did you find a reference for these polygons or did you calculate them yourself?

Comment: @MrFlick I just figured them out. It's based on a length-2 square rotated 45 degrees and a unit circle. Now that I look at it again the `sqrt(8)/7` should be `sin(pi/8)`, but it's close enough. I didn't even recognise it was a baseball field until you posted that link.

Comment: @MrFlick I don't think the image in the OP is quite the right shape for a baseball field though. I think the edited version is more accurate (though I'm Scottish, so what would I know?)

Comment: Your attention to detail here is impressive. A real home run.